# Getting nested XML data with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My excel file, called `thefilehere.xml` contains the following information:

```
<Main>
  <Name>Rotunda</Name>
  <Age>43</Age>
</Main>
<Main>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Age>22</Age>
</Main>
```

As someone who has litle experience with D3 and XML files, I am trying to understand how to call the nested data from my XML file. My basic HTML is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

My Javascript, which does not work, hopefully makes it clear what I am trying to accomplish. I want to select the main container (in this case `Main`), and from there select its children (in this case `Name` and `Age`). `Age` is to be shown via graph. `Name` is to be the label on the graph.

**JavaScript**

```
  d3.xml("thefilehere.xml", function(err, xml) {
    d3.select("#chart")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Main"))
    .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return d("Age").textContent * 1 + "px"; })
    .text(d("Name").textContent);
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer adds to and builds upon the work already done by @GerardoFurtado in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43534435/4235784) which is perfectly fine and well-suited for many situations. However, as it is often times desirable to stay within D3 to not break its basic operating concepts, here is my *D3-only*—mostly, at least— solution.

Since D3 is not restricted to handling SVG DOM trees, but is capable of handling—amongst others—XML DOM just as well, you can easily use its selections on the loaded XML file. The relevant code might look like this:

```
d3.xml(url, (error, xml) => {
  let xmlDoc = d3.select(xml.documentElement);   // wrap the XML document in a D3 selection

  d3.select("body")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(xmlDoc.selectAll("Main").nodes())      // bind the XML's nodes as data
    .enter().append("div")
      .attr("class", "myDiv")
      .style("width", d => d3.select(d).select("Age").text() * 5 + "px")
      .text(d => d3.select(d).select("Name").text());
});
```

When doing `d3.select(d)` within `.style()` and `.text()` it is important to notice, that this will actually select from the XML's DOM rather than from the HTML's DOM. Since we bound the selected elements from `xmlDoc.selectAll("Main")` as data, `d` in this case will refer to a `<Main>` element of the XML. Having this selection at hand, you can leverage D3's capabilities by doing sub-selections as well as accessing its contents by calling `.text()` and much more, if needed.

Have a look at the following snippet for a working demo:

```js
// Set up data to simulate loading from file.
// This can be ignored for the reasoning of this answer; main logic below.
const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
  `<data>
     <Main>
       <Name>Rotunda</Name>
       <Age>43</Age>
     </Main>
     <Main>
       <Name>John</Name>
       <Age>22</Age>
     </Main>
   </data>`
]));
// End of setup.

// Main logic
d3.xml(url, (error, xml) => {
  let xmlDoc = d3.select(xml.documentElement);

  d3.select("body")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(xmlDoc.selectAll("Main").nodes())
    .enter().append("div")
      .attr("class", "myDiv")
      .style("width", d => d3.select(d).select("Age").text() * 5 + "px")
      .text(d => d3.select(d).select("Name").text());
});
```

```css
.myDiv{
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good answer. It's funny that they say that `URL.createObjectURL()` is an *experimental technology*, but it's supported by all major browsers...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we'll change your XML structure, wrapping all your data inside a tag. Traditionally, this tag is named `data`:

```
<data>
    <main>
        <name>Rotunda</name>
        <age>43</age>
    </main>
    <main>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>22</age>
    </main>
</data>
```

After that, inside your `d3.xml` callback, you could simply use...

```
xml = xml.getElementsByTagName("main");
```

However, since inside `<main>` you have two tags with data, it will be awkward getting that data with `textContent`. This solution by Mike Bostock is way more interesting:

```
xml = [].map.call(xml.querySelectorAll("main"), function(d) {
    return {
        name: d.querySelector("name").textContent,
        age: +d.querySelector("age").textContent
    };
});
```

Now, you just need to use `name` and `age` in your code, which will be like this:

```
d3.xml("thefilehere.xml", function(err, xml) {

    xml = [].map.call(xml.querySelectorAll("main"), function(d) {
        return {
            name: d.querySelector("name").textContent,
            age: +d.querySelector("age").textContent
        };
    });

    d3.select("body")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(xml)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "myDiv")
        .style("width", function(d) {
            return d.age * 5 + "px";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.name
        });
});
```

Since I can't use `d3.xml` in the Stack snippet, here is a plunker with the working code: https://plnkr.co/edit/e9aCsHZnPiV4fBaPvAZv?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

To be able to get the data with `d3.xml`, you have to be serving `thefilehere.xml` from a local server.

This will **not** work if `thefilehere.xml` is simply a file in the same directory as your HTML & JS.